# Static default method for not initialized Classes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static, default

sometimes it would be convenient to have an easy way of doing the following:

```
Foo a = dosomething();
if (a != null){
    if (a.isValid()){
    ...
    }
}
```

My idea was to have some kind of static “default” methods for not initialized variables like this:

```
class Foo{
    public boolean isValid(){
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean isValid(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And now I could do this…

```
Foo a = dosomething();

if (a.isValid()){
    // In our example case -> variable is initialized and the "normal" method gets called
}else{
    // In our example case -> variable is null
}
```

So, if `a == null` the static “default” methods from our class gets called, otherwise the method of our object gets called.

Is there either some keyword I’m missing to do exactly this or is there a reason why this is not already implemented in programming languages like java/c#?

Note: this example is not very breathtaking if this would work, however there are examples where this would be - indeed - very nice.

Comment: One way to think about this would be to have a global, invalid Foo that any method could return.  Its methods work but don't do anything.  You could also return a `List<Foo>` which is empty if no Foo's were found.  But it's also OK to document that the method may return `null`, and checking is the responsibility of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

It's very slightly odd; ordinarily, `x.foo()` runs the `foo()` method as defined by the **object** that the `x` reference is pointing to. What you propose is a fallback mechanism where, if `x` is `null` (is referencing nothing) then we don't look at the object that x is pointing to (there's nothing its pointing at; hence, that is impossible), but that we look at the type of `x`, the variable itself, instead, and ask this type: Hey, can you give me the default impl of `foo()`?

The core problem is that you're assigning a definition to `null` that it just doesn't have. Your idea **requires a redefinition of what null means which means the entire community needs to go back to school**. I think the current definition of `null` in the java community is some nebulous ill defined cloud of confusion, so this is probably a good idea, but it is a huge commitment, and it is extremely easy for the OpenJDK team to dictate a direction and for the community to just ignore it. The OpenJDK team **should** be very hesitant in trying to 'solve' this problem by introducing a language feature, and they are.

Let's talk about the definitions of null that make sense, which definition of null your idea specifically is catering to (at the detriment of the other interpretations!), and how catering to that specific idea is already easy to do in current java, i.e. - what you propose sounds outright daft to me, in that it's just unneccessary and forces an opinion of what `null` means down everybody's throats for no reason.

### Not applicable / undefined / unset

This definition of `null` is **exactly** how SQL defines it, and it has the following properties:

There is **no** default implementation available. By definition! How can one define what the size is of, say, an unset list? You can't say `0`. You have no idea what the list is supposed to be. The very point is that interaction with an unset/not-applicable/unknown value should immediately lead to a result that represents either [A] the programmer messed up, the fact that they think they can interact with this value means they programmed a bug - they made an assumption about the state of the system which does not hold, or [B] that the unset nature is infectuous: The operation returns the notion 'unknown / unset / not applicable' as result.

SQL chose the B route: Any interaction with NULL in SQL land is infectuous. For example, even `NULL = NULL` in SQL is `NULL`, not `FALSE`. It also means that all booleans in SQL are tri-state, but this actually 'works', in that one can honestly fathom this notion. If I ask you: Hey, are the lights on?, then there are 3 reasonable answers: Yes, No, and I can't tell you right now; I don't know.

In my opinion, java as a language is meant for this definition as well, but has mostly chosen the [A] route: Throw an NPE to let everybody know: There is a bug, and to let the programmer get to the relevant line extremely quickly. NPEs are easy to solve, which is why I don't get why everybody hates NPEs. I love NPEs. So much better than some default behaviour that is usually but not always what I intended (objectively speaking, it is better to have 50 bugs that each takes 3 minutes to solve, than one bug that takes an an entire working day, by a large margin!) – this definition 'works' with the language:

- Uninitialized fields, and uninitialized values in an array begin as `null`, and in the absence of further information, treating it as `unset` is correct.
- They are, in fact, infectuously erroneous: Virtually all attempts to interact with them results in an exception, except `==`, but that is intentional, for the same reason in SQL `IS NULL` will return TRUE or FALSE and not NULL: Now we're actually talking about the pointer nature of the object itself (`"foo" == "foo"` can be false if the 2 strings aren't the same ref: Clearly `==` in java between objects is about the references itself and not about the objects referenced).

A key aspect to this is that **`null` has absolutely no semantic meaning, at all. Its lack of semantic meaning is the point**. In other words, `null` doesn't mean that a value is short or long or blank or indicative of anything in particular. The only thing it does mean is that it means nothing. You can't derive any information from it. Hence, `foo.size()` is **not** `0` when `foo` is unset/unknown - the question 'what is the size of the object `foo` is pointing at' is unanswerable, in this definition, and thus NPE is exactly right.

**Your idea would hurt this interpretation** - it would confound matters by giving answers to unanswerable questions.

### Sentinel / 'empty'

`null` is sometimes used as a value that **does** have semantic meaning. Something specific. For example, if you ever wrote this, you're using this interpretation:

```
if (x == null || x.isEmpty()) return false;
```

Here you've assigned a semantic meaning to `null` - the same meaning you assigned to an empty string. This is common in java and presumably stems from some bass ackwards notion of performance. For example, in the eclipse `ecj` java parser system, all empty arrays are done with null pointers. For example, the definition of a method has a field `Argument[] arguments` (for the method parameters; using argument is the slightly wrong word, but it is used to store the param definitions); however, for methods with zero parameters, the semantically correct choice is **obviously** `new Argument[0]`. However, that is NOT what `ecj` fills the Abstract Syntax Tree with, and if you are hacking around on the `ecj` code and assign `new Argument[0]` to this, other code will mess up as it just wasn't written to deal with this.

**This is in my opinion bad use of `null`**, but is quite common. And, in `ecj`'s defense, it is about 4 times faster than `javac`, so I don't think it's fair to cast aspersions at their seemingly deplorably outdated code practices. If it's stupid and it works it isn't stupid, right? `ecj` also has a better track record than `javac` (going mostly by personal experience; I've found 3 bugs in ecj over the years and 12 in javac).

This kind of `null` **does** get a lot better if we implement your idea.

### The better solution

What ecj should have done, get the best of both worlds: Make a public constant for it! `new Argument[0]`, the object, is entirely immutable. You need to make a single instance, once, ever, for an entire JVM run. The JVM itself does this; try it: `List.of()` returns the 'singleton empty list'. So does `Collections.emptyList()` for the old timers in the crowd. All lists 'made' with `Collections.emptyList()` are actually just refs to the same singleton 'empty list' object. This works because the lists these methods make are entirely immutable.

The same can and generally should apply to you!

If you ever write this:

```
if (x == null || x.isEmpty())
```

then you messed up if we go by the first definition of `null`, and you're simply writing needlessly wordy, but correct, code if we go by the second
definition. You've come up with a solution to address this, but there's a much, much better one!

Find the place where `x` got its value, and address the boneheaded code that decided to return `null` instead of `""`. You should in fact emphatically **NOT** be adding null checks to your code, because it's far too easy to get into this mode where you almost always do it, and therefore you rarely actually have null refs, but it's just swiss cheese laid on top of each other: There may still be holes, and then you get NPEs. Better to never check so you get NPEs very quickly in the development process - somebody returned `null` where they should be returning `""` instead.

Sometimes the code that made the bad null ref is out of your control. In that case, do the same thing you should always do when working with badly designed APIs: Fix it ASAP. Write a wrapper if you have to. But if you can commit a fix, do that instead. This may require *making* such an object.

### Sentinels are awesome

Sometimes sentinel objects (objects that 'stand in' for this default / blank take, such as `""` for strings, `List.of()` for lists, etc) can be a bit more fancy than this. For example, one can imagine using `LocalDate.of(1800, 1, 1)` as sentinel for a missing birthdate, but do note that this instance is not a great idea. It does crazy stuff. For example, if you write code to determine the age of a person, then it starts giving completely wrong answers (which is significantly worse than throwing an exception. With the exception you know you have a bug faster and you get a stacktrace that lets you find it in literally 500 milliseconds (just click the line, voila. That is the exact line you need to look at right now to fix the problem). It'll say someone is 212 years old all of a sudden.

But you could make a `LocalDate` object that does some things (such as: It CAN print itself; `sentinel.toString()` doesn't throw NPE but prints something like 'unset date'), but for other things it will throw an exception. For example, `.getYear()` would throw.

You can also make more than one sentinel. If you want a sentinel that means 'far future', that's trivially made (`LocalDate.of(9999, 12, 31)` is pretty good already), and you can also have one as 'for as long as anyone remembers', e.g. 'distant past'. That's cool, and not something your proposal could ever do!

You will have to deal with the consequences though. In some small ways the java ecosystem's definitions don't mesh with this, and `null` would perhaps have been a better standin. For example, the `equals` contract clearly states that `a.equals(a)` must always hold, and yet, just like in SQL `NULL = NULL` isn't `TRUE`, you probably don't want `missingDate.equals(missingDate)` to be true; that's conflating the meta with the value: You can't actually tell me that 2 missing dates are equal. By definition: The dates are missing. You do not know if they are equal or not. It is not an answerable question. And yet we can't implement the equals method of `missingDate` as `return false;` (or, better yet, as you also can't really know they aren't equal either, throw an exception) as that breaks contract (equals methods must have the identity property and must not throw, as per its own javadoc, so we can't do either of those things).

### Dealing with null better

There are a few things that make dealing with null a lot easier:

1. Annotations: APIs can and should be very clear in communicating when their methods can return `null` and what that means. Annotations to turn that documentation into compiler-checked documentation is awesome. Your IDE can start warning you, as you type, that null may occur and what that means, and will say so in auto-complete dialogs too. And it's all entirely backwards compatible in all senses of the word: No need to start considering giant swaths of the java ecosystem as 'obsolete' (unlike Optional, which mostly sucks).
2. Optional, except this is a non-solution. The type isn't orthogonal (you can't write a method that takes a `List<MaybeOptionalorNot<String>>` that works on both `List<String>` and `List<Optional<String>>`, even though a method that checks the 'is it some or is it none?' state of all list members and doesn't add anything (except maybe shuffle things around) would work equally on both methods, and yet you just can't write it. This is bad, and it means all usages of optional must be 'unrolled' on the spot, and e.g. `Optional<X>` should show up pretty much never ever as a parameter type or field type. Only as return types and even that is dubious - I'd just stick to what Optional was made for: As return type of Stream terminal operations.

Adopting it also isn't backwards compatible. For example, `hashMap.get(key)` should, in all possible interpretations of what Optional is for, obviously return an `Optional<V>`, but it doesn't, and it never will, because java doesn't break backwards compatibility lightly and breaking that is obviously far too heavy an impact. The only real solution is to introduce `java.util2` and a complete incompatible redesign of the collections API, which is splitting the java ecosystem in twain. Ask the python community (python2 vs. python3) how well that goes.

3. Use sentinels, use them heavily, make them available. If I were designing LocalDate, I'd have created `LocalDate.FAR_FUTURE` and `LocalDate_DISTANT_PAST` (but let it be clear that I think Stephen Colebourne, who designed JSR310, is perhaps the best API designer out there. But nothing is so perfect that it can't be complained about, right?)
4. Use API calls that allow defaulting. Map has this.

Do NOT write this code:

```java
String phoneNr = phoneNumbers.get(userId);
if (phoneNr == null) return "Unknown phone number";
return phoneNr;
```

But DO write this:

```java
return phoneNumbers.getOrDefault(userId, "Unknown phone number");
```

Don't write:

```
Map<Course, List<Student>> participants;
void enrollStudent(Student student) {
  List<Student> participating = participants.get(econ101);
  if (participating == null) {
    participating = new ArrayList<Student>();
    participants.put(econ101, participating);
  }
  participating.add(student);
}
```

instead write:

```java
Map<Course, List<Student>> participants;
void enrollStudent(Student student) {
  participants.computeIfAbsent(econ101,
    k -> new ArrayList<Student>())
    .add(student);
}
```

and, crucially, if you are writing APIs, ensure things like `getOrDefault`, `computeIfAbsent`, etc. are available so that the users of your API don't have to deal with `null` nearly as much.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static `test()` method like this:

```
static <T> boolean test(T object, Predicate<T> validation) {
    return object != null && validation.test(object);
}
```

and

```
static class Foo {
    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }
}

static Foo dosomething() {
    return new Foo();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo a = dosomething();
    if (test(a, Foo::isValid))
        System.out.println("OK");
    else
        System.out.println("NG");
}
```

output:

```
OK
```

If `dosomething()` returns `null`, it prints `NG`

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly, but take a look at `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(dosomething())
        .filter(Foo::isValid)
        .ifPresent(a -> ...);
```